# Xcode Objective-c Compile Time Conditional

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, compilation

I'm working on an iOS project in xcode and I'd like to include different codes depending on the build scheme. ie: For anything except the Distribution on an iOS Device scheme, I'd like to include a bunch of debug stuff. But for the Distribution on an iOS Device scheme, I don't want to include the debug stuff.

If I can add some sort of conditional code block it will be very helpful as it will eliminate the chance of me forgetting to change the flag manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default when you create a new XCode 4 project it will add `DEBUG` to your `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` (Preprocessor Macros) under build settings so you can do the following.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    //Debug only code here
#endif
```

If you need more preprocessor definitions add them under `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` or `OTHER_CFLAGS` or `OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS` [prefix the last 2 with `-D`] for the correct build configuration.

Comment: Ended up using this site to figure out how to define DEBUG flag in xcode 4: http://whomwah.com/2011/05/31/loggingdebug-setup-in-xcode-4/

Comment: And I used this site to leverage these compile-time conditional statements: http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/